# Traefik unable to connect document server to nextcloud

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik, nextcloud, onlyoffice

I'm fairly new to Traefik (v2.11) and having difficulty setting up Nextcloud+OnlyOffice.

I think a piece is missing because even though the path is correct I just can't open OnlyOffice from Nextcloud.

IP Addresses:

- Traefik: 10.10.10.70
- Nextcloud: 10.10.10.73

Error:

> connect to cloud.my-domain.com port 443 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://cloud.my-domain.com/index.php/apps/documentserver_community/healthcheck)

Nextcloud configuration file:

**config/config.php**

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'instanceid' => 'oce5onoj6xn7',
  'passwordsalt' => 'JNjRafts37dfyhdiuf/nwD+k5',
  'secret' => '89y45h23i4h32uj423978h23jk4n3un234wqda',
  'trusted_proxies' => 
  array (
          0 => '10.10.10.70',
  ),
  'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
          0 => 'cloud.my-domain.com',
          1 => '10.10.10.73',
          2 => '10.10.10.70',
  ),
  'overwriteprotocol' => 'https',
  'overwritehost' => 'cloud.my-domain.com',
  'overwritecondaddr' => '^10\.10\.10\.70$',
  'datadirectory' => '/srv/nextcloud/data',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '28.0.3.2',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://cloud.my-domain.com',
  'dbname' => 'nextclouddb',
  'dbhost' => 'localhost',
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,
  'dbuser' => 'nextclouduser',
  'dbpassword' => 'nextcloudpass',
  'installed' => true,
);
```

Traefik config files:

**/etc/traefik/traefik.toml**

```
[log]
  level = "DEBUG"
  filePath = "/var/log/traefik/debug.log"

[accessLog]
  filePath =  "/var/log/traefik/access.log"
  bufferingSize =  100

[providers]
  [providers.file]
    filename = "/etc/traefik/traefik-dynamic.toml"

[api]
  dashboard = true
  debug = true

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.web-secure]
    address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.dashboard]
    address = ":8080"

[certificatesResolvers.sample.acme]
  email = "info@my-domain.com"
  storage = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"

  [certificatesResolvers.sample.acme.httpChallenge]
  # used during the challenge
    entryPoint = "web"
```

**/etc/traefik/traefik-dynamic.toml**

```
[http]
  # Redirect to https
  [http.middlewares]
    [http.middlewares.test-redirectscheme.redirectScheme]
      scheme = "https"
    [http.middlewares.auth.basicAuth]
     # generate password hash form cli or online generators like https://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator
      users = [
          "admin:$secret-password"
        ]

  [http.routers]

    ## cloud ##
    [http.routers.cloud]
      rule = "Host(`cloud.my-domain.com`)"
      service = "cloud"
      entryPoints = ["web-secure"]
    [http.routers.cloud.tls]
      certResolver = "sample"

     ## traefik dashboard ##
    [http.routers.dashboard]
      rule = "Host(`www.my-domain.com`) && (PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`))"
      entryPoints = ["web-secure"]
      service = "api@internal"
      middlewares = ["auth"]
    [http.routers.dashboard.tls]
    #  certResolver = "sample"

[http.services]
    [http.services.cloud.loadbalancer]
      [[http.services.cloud.loadbalancer.servers]]
        url = "http://10.10.10.73"
```

Apart from the integration between the document server and OnlyOffice, the rest of Nextcloud seems to work correctly, I don't understand..